# awsインスタンスに接続できない

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

タイトルの通りですがEC2インスタンスに接続できません。

先日1週間ぶりに接続しようとしたところ接続ができなかった(特に何も設定はいじっていない)ので一度インスタンスを再起動しました。そのところサイト自体も接続ができなくなってしまいました。おそらくターミナルからapacheを起動させなければいけないと思うのですが、インスタンスに接続ができないのでそれができません。

**接続方法**

- teratermでssh接続(elastic ipを使用)
- awsコンソールからインスタンスの停止、起動を実行

**手順**

1. ssh接続をしようとした
2. タイムアウトしてつながらない(インスタンスは正常に動いている)
3. インスタンスを停止
4. インスタンスを起動
5. サイトが表示されなくなる
6. インスタンスを停止
7. インスタンスを起動
8. sshログインできないまま

aws初心者ですが、どなたか解決方法がわかる方がいたら教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 接続方法、従った手順などもう少し情報を書かれた方が良いと思います。状況がつかめないので、わかるかたでも教えづらいと思います。

Comment: 接続方法はteratermでssh接続(elastic ipを使用)
awsコンソールからインスタンスの停止、起動を実行
手順
1.ssh接続をしようとした
2.タイムアウトしてつながらない(インスタンスは正常に動いている)
3.インスタンスを停止
4.インスタンスを起動
5.サイトが表示されなくなる
6.インスタンスを停止
7.インスタンスを起動
8.sshログインできないまま

上記のような流れになるのですが、接続方法、従った手順としてこれで
正しい回答ができていますでしょうか？

Comment: コンソール出力を確認するとログインプロンプトは表示されてますか？ご参考：https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Comment: まだ解決できてなければですが、インスタンスに不具合が出ている場合はサポートフォーラムで質問するとAmazonの中の人が復旧してくれる場合がありますのでお試しください。